# Extracting C++ comment in source code with Python and Regular Expression

Tags: python, c++, regex

I am working on a project that require that I should extract comments from C++ source code irrespective of where it is located. It can be of single line or multiple line comment.

I have the following as data input in txt file, which was read into the program.

```
    /* this is a comment in C. This comment syntax is guaranteed to work
    on every compiler */ and
    // This is also a comment in C. but it might present portability
    challenges
    Fortran

    ! This is a comment in Fortran

    C++

    // This is single Line Comment in C++
    /* This is multi line comment.
    in C++
    */
```

My task is to extract the human readable comment part excluding the comment tag, Hence using python and regular expression,below is my implementation, I have this function in my python code:

```
    def cplusComment(self,content):
       for comment in re.findall(r'\/\*((.*?)|(\n))*\/', content, re.S):
           yield comment
```

The above function is been call in this section of the code here:

```
    def commentdata(self, content):
        for con in content.read():
           for k in self.cplusComment(con):
               print(k, 'what is this k meant for')
```

my output is empty list of this format:

```
    ('', '', '')
```

and what I am expecting should be

```
    this is a comment in C. This comment syntax is guaranteed to work
    on every compiler
    This is also a comment in C. but it might present portability
    challenges
    This is multi line comment in C++
```

I will appreciate if i can be guide to the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lenik is right. But for this example

```
pattern = re.compile('(?:/\*(.*?)\*/)|(?://(.*?)\n)',re.S)
pattern.findall(s)
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks, It should be noted that Regex version you suggested extract one line comment in C++ code but not when the comment span multiple line. I will be looking into what @lenik said, as that it is closer to what i intend to achieve with project.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reliably solve this problem without building a full blown C parser, because there are strings, and nested comments, and the `/*` sequence can be easily inside the string, like `printf( "/* is this a comment or what?" );`, etc.

Moreover, `/*` and `*/` sometimes are used to comment out parts of the code, sometimes quite large blocks, without commenting every line with `//`, are those code blocks the comments you want to get as your program output? Probably not...

Here is a link that might get you going in the right direction: [Complete C99 parser in pure Python](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser)

Comment: Maybe not a full blown parser, but you have to handle at least strings, line continuation and possibly a decent subset of the preprocessor.

Comment: You need a lexer, not a full-blown parser.